# Let `magit-insert-local-branches` sort branches according to the branch.sort configuration

Tags: magit

Is it possible to configure magit to sort branches inserted with `magit-insert-local-branches` into the main status page according to some criteria, for example whatever is configured as `branch.sort` in the git configuration?

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be possible out of the box with version 20220919. The function which reads the branches is `magit-refs--format-local-branches` in magit-refs.el. It calls `magit-git-lines` to run `git for-each-ref` with suitable parameters to get the branch names. The variable `magit-buffer-arguments` is passed as an argument too, but this variable is not settable (and would not make sense to be settable) for the status page.

As explained in the comments to https://stackoverflow.com/q/73800506/2954288, using `git config for-each-ref.sort -committerdate` can not work, since `for-each-ref` does not care about configuration options.

Patching magit sensibly seems difficult, since there is just no concept to pass configured parameters to `magit-refs--format-local-branches`.

Hacking it by inserting `"--sort=-committerdate"` in the right place does work, but may have side effects I did not experience and will be overwritten with the next update.